# Is it possible to log the files used in a SSIS package to a custom execution table?

Tags: sql, ssis

I've made a SSIS package that loads 1 or more files into a series of tables. I want to track which files were used in the package and store them in a table, ideally with the following columns:

1. ETL ID - same for each file used in that load
2. File name
3. Date run

I've read multiple articles online that use the SSIS logging feature but that only seems to record the package that was run not the files used within the package.

Is it possible to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create custom logging but I have found the use of an `Execute SQL Task` far easier and portable.

My packages generally take this form

[image: AuditWorkAudit]

I audit the package's start, do work, and then record package completion. This pattern should work for you. The Begin Audit step would look something like

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyAudit
SELECT ? AS EtlId, ? AS StartDate;
```

Then when package completes, backfill with run data like so

```
UPDATE dbo.MyAudit
SET SourceFile = ?, EndDate = ?, RowsInserted = ?, RowsUpdated = ?
WHERE RunId = ?;
```

The question marks, `?`, are ordinal place holders in the Execute SQL Task which get wired up to Parameters (SSIS Variables), assuming you're using OLE DB Connection Manager.

Also, possibly relevant -> [getting current file name](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2016/05/ssis-what-is-name-of-file.html)

Comment: Just got a version of this working. Thank you very much your reply!